Using Cramer's rule and block matrix methods to compute determinants and components of a vector $\vec{x}$
I am continuing to work through a text on linear algebra and have encountered the following problem:

Question: Suppose $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$ and that $A\vec{x} = \vec{y}$, in which
\begin{equation*}
A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
a & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7 \\
c & b & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
a & d & a & 2 & 0 & 0 & 7 \\
d & b & c & b & 1 & 0 & 4 \\
c & a & c & d & a & 2 & 7 \\
a & c & b & d & c & b & 1
\end{bmatrix}, \quad \vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5 \\ x_6 \\ 4\end{bmatrix}, \quad \vec{y} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
Using this information, compute $\det A$ and $x_4$.

The question also offers the hint that the solutions will not involve the constants $a, b, c, d$.

My Attempt: Denote the matrix obtained by replacing the $i$th column of $A$ by $\vec{y}$ as $A_i(\vec{y})$. Cramer's rule says that
\begin{equation*} x_i = \frac{\det A_i(y)}{\det A} \end{equation*}
for all $i = 1, 2, \ldots, 7$. Observe that if we replace the final column of $A$ by $\vec{y}$, we get an upper triangular matrix. Multiplying the entries on the main diagonal to get the determinant, we find that $\det A_7(\vec{y}) = 8$. Since $x_7 = 4$, we find that
\begin{equation*} 4 = \frac{8}{\det A} \implies \det A = 2. \end{equation*}
We now pivot to trying to solve for $x_4$. Construct the matrix
\begin{equation*} A_4(\vec{y}) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
a & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7 \\
c & b & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
a & d & a & 0 & 0 & 0 & 7 \\
d & b & c & 0 & 1 & 0 & 4 \\
c & a & c & 0 & a & 2 & 7 \\
a & c & b & 1 & c & b & 1
\end{bmatrix} \end{equation*}

This is where issues arise for me: any method I use to try to compute the determinant seems to depend on $a, b, c, d$, which would mean that $x_4$ would depend on $a, b, c, d$, contradicting the hint. The way the problem is structured suggests as well that there should be some "easy" way to compute the determinant that I'm missing.
The two methods that I've tried that have come up short are computing it in the "standard way" by taking a Laplace expansion down the fourth column, and continuing to take Laplace expansions down the columns/rows with the most zeroes. This yielded an (unsimplified) answer of $-2[14 - 7d + ad - 2a] + 2a[8 - 7b + 4(ab - 2c)]$, provided I didn't make any computation mistakes.
The other method I tried to potentially make the computation easier is by treating $A$ as a bordered matrix
\begin{equation*} A = \begin{bmatrix} B & \vec{v} \\ \vec{w}^T & c \end{bmatrix}. \end{equation*}
The Cauchy expansion says that
\begin{equation*}
\det A = c \det B - \vec{w}^T(\text{adj } B)\vec{v}.
\end{equation*}
While it is clear that $\det B$ is zero, this method doesn't seem to simplify anything either as computing the adjugate remains difficult (the terms in its fourth row all will depend on $a, b, c, d$). I am wondering if there is anything I'm missing here.

Have you tried a computer solution with different values for the parameters, just to verify the hint?

The smart-aleck solution would be to assume the information in the hint and set all the parameters to zero. But that's probably not what the problem writer intended

@MatthewLeingang I realize now I probably should have done this before! The hint seems to be incorrect. Using a computer the determinant of $A_4(y)$ seems to be $32a+8a^2b - 14ab - 16ac - 8ad + 14d - 28$ for arbitrary $a, b, c, d$, and checking for a few values of the parameters this seems to hold ($a = b = c = d = 0$ yields $-28$, for example). It does make me wonder what the problem writer intended in solving this problem!

Sounds like you answered your own question. I encourage you to write an answer to close it out.
